# regular expression for the whole string

Tags: java, regex

Below code stuff will parse the  `(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)` string and will display the values on iteration. The code is working fine but my thought is that can we write regular expression for the whole string and can we able get values like `matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4), matcher.group(5), matcher.group(6), matcher.group(7), matcher.group(8)`

My code is as given below

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");

while (matcher.find()) {
   int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
   int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
   System.out.printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @hwnd then how to get the eight values

Comment: How do you expect the output?

Comment: @hwnd I want to get all the eight values i.e `8, 0, 0, -1, 7, -2, 1, 1` without while loop

Comment: @AlexMan: It's not possible without the while loop. There is no "findall" API in Java.

Comment: Replace the parenthesis with empty string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to have the fastest way of receiving the eight values then use the suggestion in the comments. Replace the parenthesis with an empty String. Then split the whole String by a comma and translate the values to integers.

I ran a benchmark for you to show you how fast each approach is:

```
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testRegexLoop     avgt   30  1232,524 ± 42,972  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRegexWhole    avgt   30  2638,561 ± 59,419  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testReplaceSplit  avgt   30  1045,388 ± 66,791  ns/op
```

To reproduce the results:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

@Fork(3)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Threads(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {

  Blackhole bh = new Blackhole();

  @Benchmark
  public void testRegexLoop() {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");

    while (matcher.find()) {
      int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
      int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
      bh.consume(x);
      bh.consume(y);
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testRegexWhole() {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");
    matcher.find();
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(6)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(7)));
    bh.consume(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(8)));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testReplaceSplit() {
    String s = "(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)";
    String[] values = s.replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",");
    int[] intValues = new int[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
    }
    bh.consume(intValues);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it, you need to make all 8 groups in your regex pattern, just like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\),\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
```

And in that case you can call a single find() and get all the groups from first to last. But it seems a little bit hard to read such a code. And this won't work if the number of pair of doubles will change in time.

Comment: Can't say at the moment, is that way faster, then the one with a loop. I don't realy think, that for such a short string you can get any valuable improvement. The no loop decision can be a little bit faster, but  in that case you need to check a harder regex, so you need to test it yourself, if you want to check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GetNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)";
        String d2 = "[-]?\\d";
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(d2).matcher(s1);
        while (m.find()) {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
        }

        for (String str : allMatches){
             System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

yields

```
8
0
0
-1
7
-2
1
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```